# XQuery to get list of attributes

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery

If I have several `Section` elements in an XML document, what XQuery do I use to get a list of all the `name` values?

```
<Section name="New Clients" filePath="XNEWCUST.TXT" skipSection="False">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 (which is a subset of XQuery) one would use the following expression to get a sequence of all string values of the "name" attributes of the "Section" elements:

```xquery
for $attr in //Section/@name
 return string($attr)
```

Do note that using the "//" abbreviation is typically a bad practice as this may require a whole (subtree) to be traversed. In any case where the structure of the document is known a more specific XPath expression (such as one using specific location steps) should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed was a return concat(string($attr), "-") to delimit the values.

Answer (score 1):

```xquery
//Section/@name
```

or

```xquery
//Section/@name/string(.)
```

for the string values

Answer (score 0):

```
 /Section/@name
```

Comment: This will select the "name" attribute node of the only top element of the XML document, if the top element happens to be a "Section" element. What the OP wanted is the sequence of the *string values* of the "name" attributes of *all* "Section" elements in the XML document.