# Way to list XML entities in SQL Server using xml methods?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

SQL Server 2005/2008.

I've searched and read several questions here and elsewhere and in BOL, but none I've found so far directly answer this question.

Given

```
declare @xml xml = '<Root> <Ent foo="abc" bar="def" /> </Root>'
```

Is there a way to get a result set of something like

```
col1        col2
-----------------
foo         abc
bar         def
```

I know how to do this by using sp_xml_preparedocument and OPENXML, I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it directly using the xml methods.  I haven't been able to find anything in BOL or Googling, but just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this question and answer help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324289/xquery-to-get-list-of-attributes

Comment: Sorry, it's at times like these I realize things I left out.  As with the calls to sp_xml_preparedocument and OPENXML, I'm trying to do this in T-SQL.

Comment: SQL Server does, within T-SQL, have a subset of XQuery available.  That's why I pointed at that particular question.  I haven't had time to look into your inquiry further, but it seems like the purpose of the earlier question was similar to the purpose of your current question.

Comment: Yes, it does appear it was the purpose, but it's not in T-SQL, and I have not been able to coax the T-SQL XML methods into doing anything like what is in that question. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, query() method works slower then value(). So i recommend use value() method:

```
 SELECT
    b.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(MAX)') as col1,
    b.value('data(.)','nvarchar(MAX)') as col2
FROM @xml.nodes('//Root/Ent/@*') a(b)
```

Comparing with previous answer, it is about 3 times faster.

Comment: This is a much better solution. +1

Comment: Agreed, and sorry it took so long to say so!

Comment: vr8ce , no problem. I hope it was helpful for the author.

Answer (score 3):

This might give you a starting point to get you what you need.

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<Root> <Ent foo="abc" bar="def" /> </Root>';

WITH [Attributes]([xml])
AS
(
    SELECT
        @xml.query
        ('
            for $x in (/Root/Ent/@*)
            return <attribute name="{local-name($x)}" value="{data($x)}"/>
        ')
)
SELECT
    [Attribute].[data].value(N'@name', N'nvarchar(max)') AS [col1],
    [Attribute].[data].value(N'@value', N'nvarchar(max)') AS [col2]
FROM
    [Attributes]
CROSS APPLY
    [xml].nodes(N'attribute') AS [Attribute]([data]);
```

Comment: Fascinating. That's some serious T-SQL and XML-fu. :)  This is what the question Andrew referred was doing, but I wasn't smart enough to translate it into T-SQL.  Thanks very much!